# Need F# Map.fold example

Tags: f#

I can’t find a simple working example of the use of  `Map.fold` anywhere.  I have seen the [F# for fun and profit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recursive-types-and-folds-2b/) and the [MSFT documents on ‘fold’](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-mapmodule.html).

Can you provide a short working example of the use of  `Map.fold`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let capitals =
    [("Australia", "Canberra"); ("Canada", "Ottawa"); ("China", "Beijing");
        ("Denmark", "Copenhagen"); ("Egypt", "Cairo"); ("Finland", "Helsinki");
        ("France", "Paris"); ("Germany", "Berlin"); ("India", "New Delhi");
        ("Japan", "Tokyo"); ("Mexico", "Mexico City"); ("Russia", "Moscow");
        ("Slovenia", "Ljubljana"); ("Spain", "Madrid"); ("Sweden", "Stockholm");
        ("Taiwan", "Taipei"); ("USA", "Washington D.C.")]
    |> Map.ofList

printfn "%A\n" capitals

printfn "%s" 
    (Map.fold 
        (fun acc key value -> (acc + "(" + key + "," + value + ")")) 
        "" 
        capitals)
```